# How to apply meta-tables on Lua functions in order to enable custom operators between them?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to set a meta-table on specific functions to enable a custom operator for functional composition between them.

The reason I want to introduce a composition operator in my library is because I don't want to nest the argument parentheses one into another like this: `f(g(h(x)))` but rather: `f * g * h(x)`, or something alike that doesn't require nesting parentheses.

So far I had two approaches to achieve my goal:

1. Attempt to set a `__mul` meta-method for Lua functions, I'm not sure how exactly.
2. Re-define all the compositable functions as callable functionally-composite tables via meta-tables, by providing meta-methods for `__call` and `__mul`.

I wrote an experimental (and a working) [implementation](https://gist.github.com/david-tamar/cd4b8d27fb1282f227f31a15bd501f63) for the 2nd approach today (functionally-composite tables). But I don't think it's elegant, it's rather a hack with significant overhead in memory and processing for what is merely syntactic sugar. It's so complex that it has its own call-stack queue because Lua evaluates custom operators left-associative <strike>while functional composition is actually right-associative</strike> (I mistakenly thought so when I implemented it, and it turned out necessary for a whole different reason. See in the comments).

My current attempt to implement the 1st approach with functions and meta-tables looks like this:

```
local compositable =
{
    __mul = function(a, b)
        a(b)
    end
}

local function f(x) return x*x end
local function g(x) return -x end

setmetatable(f, compositable) -- Error, table expected, got function.
setmetatable(g, compositable) -- "

local result = f * g(4)

print(result) -- Expected result: -16
```

But this doesn't work, it appears that only Lua tables and strings are allowed to be set with a meta-tables in Lua.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Properties), function composition is associative, so there's no need to make `__mul` right-associative.

Comment: @luther, oops. Sorry, I'll correct this. However it turns out that I had to implement this operator as right-associative for a different reason (because then the underlying functions will receive from the left composite tables that were not yet evaluated instead of actual numerical values to compute with). I'll try to look deeper into this tonight and review my code again and see if I could re-implement this without right-association.

Comment: So you're really trying to change operator precedence by evaluating `*` before function calls. I recommend just invoking like `(f * g)(x)`. Changing operator precedence can make code hard to read by violating basic assumptions about syntax. Note that you won't always need the parentheses, because you won't always immediately call the new function. It's common to store a composed function to a variable or to pass it as an argument, just like an anonymous function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While all Lua values can have metatables, `setmetatable` *only* sets metatables for tables. Tables and full userdata can have metatables set on individual values, while values of different types all *share* a metatable for each type. All strings have the same metatable, for example.

So you can't set a metatable for a function, but you can set a metatable for *all functions*. Only the `debug` library can do that, through `debug.setmetatable`. Again, this will apply to *all functions everywhere*.

Comment: Hi Nicol, thanks for the answer. Do you think it'd be appropriate to use the `debug` library for non-debug purposes like composing functions in this case? I've read elsewhere that the `debug` library should be reserved only for introspection and analyzing errors, so the end user shouldn't rely on `debug`. I guess there's no elegant way to achieve what I want without altering Lua itself in C?

Comment: @DavidTamar: You are effectively hacking Lua to transform it into a language of your own design, where functions have specialized operators that cause behaviors unknown to regular Lua functions. I think you could call that a form of "introspection".

Comment: Hi Nicol, I want to inform you that my assumption regarding the right-associativity of functional composition was actually incorrect and now I corrected this in my original post thanks to Luther's comment. (Note that despite this, I still had to implement the operator as right-associative because I didn't want to send composite tables instead of numerical values into the underlying functions. But that is not the original reason that I stated in my opening question.)

Comment: Hello - "setmetatable only sets metatables for tables" - Thats not true. Check (Lua5.3): ```getmetatable(_VERSION)``` And also you can 
 change them or set for example a __call meta function on strings.

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi: You can retrieve a metatable for non-table values, but you cannot *set* such a metatable with `setmetatable`. You *have* to use the `debug` library's version of the function.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to write `(f * g)(x)`. Then the code below works.

```
debug.setmetatable(function()end,
    {__mul=function (f,g) return function (x) return f(g(x)) end end})

function f(x) return x*x end
function g(x) return -x end

print((f*g)(2))
print((g*f)(2))
```

This code is a bit wasteful because it creates a composite function in every call.

Comment: “it creates a composite function in every call” - This worries me a lot. I don't want to create massive performance overheads for code maintenance. I'm also trying to avoid the debug library for actual usage of my module. 

I had a new idea today about processing the composition itself with a separate function like that: `composite(f, g, h) (x, y, z)`, I think it's more Lua-ish, and its implementation is rather straightforward and not so hacky. What do you think, any drawbacks?